# Installing YADR on Ubuntu 14.04 error - prezto: old shell detected

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, virtualbox

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox, and I am trying to install YADR (https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles), which works really well on Mac OS X. However, after I finished installing and restarted my terminal, the YADR configuration doesn't seem to get applied. Thus, I tried doing

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Yet I get this:

```
Error: no such file "prezto: old shell detected, minimum required: 4.3.11"
bash: /home/afif/.zshrc: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/afif/.zshrc: line 15: `for config_file ($HOME/.yadr/zsh/*.zsh)
source $config_file'
```

A quick check on my bash --version shows that I actually have GNU Bash 4.3.11.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old question but for future reference for (U/Ku/Xu/...)buntu users I would like to answer this question.

After installing YADR respository(skwp one), just run the following commands in your terminal and you'll be up and running with YADR

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

This will install **Zsh** on your system and will allow you to use YADR.

To use it in your current session run:

```
zsh
```

Or to make this change permanent run:

```
chsh
```

It will ask you for your password and it will ask the new value for your login shell, enter this there:

```
/bin/zsh
```

And reboot!

If everythin runs smoothly then the configuration file(~/.zshrc) will be automatically loaded by Zsh, if not then just run:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Nice first answers!

Answer (score -1):

YADR is not meant to work in ubuntu., you may wish to try an ubuntu variant, such as : https://github.com/renoirb/ubuntu-yadr

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @pilot6 I totally agree, but if someone asks why a hammer won't unscrew, the only response is "you're dealing with a screw, try a screwdriver"